# Are there any (valid) C implementations where float cannot represent the value 0?

Tags: c, floating-point

If all floats are represented as `x = (-1)^s * 2^e * 1.m` , there is no way to store zero without support for special cases.

Comment: Please don't close this. The question is clear enough. Most floating-point formats use an implicit leading 1 in the mantissa/significand; a special case is required to represent zero.

Comment: Which, if any, C standard are you referring to when you say "valid"?  It wouldn't surprise me if there's at least one K&R C implementation for at least one weird old supercomputer that doesn't have floating-point 0.

Comment: It might be valid, the odds that you'll find somebody using it are 0.0 of course.  Silly question.

Comment: @tmyklebu I want know, what says the C-Standards about it and if anybody know a implementation there not support floating-point value 0.0

Comment: @tmyklebu: It would astonish me. I've read about a lot of truly bizarre floating-point systems; I've never heard of a real-world implementation that can't represent `0.0`. And as I argue in my answer, such an implementation would be non-conforming, even for K&R1 (my copy isn't handy, but a C manual from 1975 says "The initial value of any externally-defined object not explicitly initialized is guaranteed to be 0."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, all conforming C implementations must support a floating-point value of `0.0`.

The floating-point model is described in section 5.2.4.2.2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to a recent draft). That model does not make the leading `1` in the significand (sometimes called the mantissa) implicit, so it has no problem representing `0.0`.

Most implementations of binary floating-point don't store the leading `1`, and in fact the formula you cited in the question:

```
x = (-1)^s * 2^e * 1.m
```

is typically correct (though the way `e` is stored can vary).

In such implementations, including IEEE, a special-case bit pattern, typically all-bits-zero, is used to represent `0.0`.

Following up on the discussion in the comments, tmyklebu argues that not all numbers defined by the floating-point model in 5.2.4.2.2 are required to be representable. I disagree; if not all such numbers are required to be representable, then the model is nearly useless. But even leaving that argument aside, there is an explicit requirement that `0.0` must be representable. N1570 6.7.9 paragraph 10:

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not
>   initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - ...
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - ...

This is a very long-standing requirement. A [C reference from 1975](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf) (3 years before the publication of K&R1) says:

> The initial value of any externally-defined object not explicitly initialized is guaranteed to be 0.

which implies that there must be a representable 0 value. K&R1 (published in 1978) says, on page 198:

> Static and external variables which are not initialized are guaranteed
>   to start off as 0; automatic and register variables which are not
>   initialized are guaranteed to start off as garbage.

Interestingly, the 1990 ISO C standard (equivalent to the 1989 ANSI C standard) is slightly less explicit than its predecessors and successors. In 6.5.7, it says:

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has
>   arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type
>   were assigned a null pointer constant.

*If* a floating-point type were not required to have an exact representation for `0.0`, then the "assigned 0" phrase would imply a conversion from the `int` value `0` to the floating-point type, yielding a small value *close* to `0.0`. Still, C90 has the same floating-point model as C99 and C11 (but with no mention of subnormal or unnormalized values), and my argument above about model numbers still applies. Furthermore, the C90 standard was officially superseded by C99, which in turn was superseded by C11.

Comment: But note that the C standard does not require support of subnormal and unnormalized numbers (nonzero numbers which do not have the leading `1`). So 0 is really a special case, even in the C standard.

Comment: @interjay: In the C model in 5.2.4.2.2, setting all the significand digits (typically bits) to `0` gives you a value of `0.0`, regardless of the values of the sign and exponent. So, unless I'm missing something, `0.0` doesn't *have* to be a special case.

Comment: I just read 5.2.4.2.2 and I don't see how you inferred that there's a floating-point number `z` such that `z + z == z` and `z + 1 == 1`.

Comment: @KeithThompson It's a special case because of 5.2.4.2.2 paragraph 3. The only type required to be supported is normalized floating point, where `f1>0` if `x!=0`. `x` is the number here and `f1` is the leading digit, so as you can see it mentions zero specifically.

Comment: @tmyklebu: If all the significand digits *f-sub-k* are zero, then the value is `0.0`, regardless of the values of *s* (the sign) and *e* (the exponent). The tricky thing that makes this question relevant is that `f-sub-1` is *almost* always `1` (assuming *b*, the base, is 2), so many implementations don't bother to store it, requiring a special case to represent `0.0`. The floating-point model in the standard doesn't require that special case -- which makes the mapping from the model in the standard to actual implementations non-trivial.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Where does it say that, for any valid assignment of values to the f_k's and any reasonable sign and exponent, there exists a floating-point number with that representation?  As you note, IEEE doubles can't represent unnormalised floating-point numbers.  Footnote 21 also appears to support this position.

Comment: @tmyklebu: In the model given in the standard, assign zero to *s*, to *e*, and to all *f_k*. That's a representation of `0.0`. I didn't say that IEEE doubles can't represent unnormalized numbers; as far as I know they can. The definition of a normalized number is "(*f_1* > 0 if *x* ≠ 0); note "if", not "and". All-bits-zero is a normalized representation of `0.0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Where does the standard guarantee that any assignment of `s`, `e`, and `f_k` that abide by the implementation-defined bounds corresponds to a floating-point number?  All I can see is how it states that, apart from weird cases, every floating-point number corresponds to an `s`, and `e`, and a bunch of `f_k`s.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Interesting question. "In addition to normalized floating-point numbers ... floating types may be able to contain other kinds of floating-point numbers ...". I think there's an implicit assumption that all normalized representations are valid and have the values specified by the model. I'd be happier if that were stated explicitly, but I don't see a *sensible* interpretation that would permit all-bits-zero (or whatever that maps to in the actual implementation) to be invalid.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I don't see where it says that there *is* anything that all-bits-zero "maps to in the actual implementation."  I'd even hazard a guess that there is a floating-point system allowed by the C standard that doesn't have an additive identity.  [This paper by William Kahan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/why-ieee.pdf) mentions a few idiosyncracies of various old, weird floating-point systems.  It's not clear that all of these horrible things are forbidden by C.

Comment: @tmyklebu: If not every normalized number described by the model is necessarily representable in a conforming implementation, then the model is practically useless. If `0.0` doesn't need to be representable, what about `1.0`? What about a system that can't represent negative numbers? There's a lot of vague wording in the standard; I suggest that many (not all) of the ambiguities can be reasonably resolved by assuming that normative wording is actually intended to mean something.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The C standard apparently does not care if floating-point numbers are useful.  I think this is so that all the weird old floating-point systems can be used in a conforming C implementation.

Comment: @tmyklebu: "The C standard apparently does not care if floating-point numbers are useful." I simply do not believe that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The first couple paragraphs of [this interview with Kahan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/754story.html) allude to some of the crazy things that historical FP systems actually had.  (I wish it said which computers these were.)  In order that C implementations using native arithmetic can be called "conforming", the C standard needs to permit crazy floating-point systems.  It does this by imposing almost no constraints on how FP arithmetic works.  Annex F defines FP semantics that aren't crappy, but it does not require them.

Answer (score 2):

After o search a while a found this.

ISO/IEC 9899:201x section 6.2.5, Paragraph 13

> Each complex type has the same representation and alignment requirements as an array
>   type containing exactly two elements of the corresponding real type; the first element is
>   equal to the real part, and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

section 6.3.1.7, Paragraph 1

> When a value of real type is converted to a complex type, the real part of the complex
>   result value is determined by the rules of conversion to the corresponding real type and
>   the imaginary part of the complex result value is a positive zero or an unsigned zero.

So, if i understand this right, any implementations where supports C99 (first C standard with _Complex types), must support a floating-point value of 0.0.

**EDIT**
Keith Thompson pointed out that complex types are optional in C99, so this argument is pointless.

Comment: Good catch! But as of the 2011 standard (which officially supersedes the 1999 standard), complex types are an optional feature. But I think the requirement that static objects with no explicit initializer must be initialized to zero nails it for all versions of C (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following floating-point system is an example of a conforming floating-point arithmetic without a representation for zero:

A `float` is a 48-bit number with one sign bit, 15 exponent bits, and 32 significand bits.  Every choice of sign bit, exponent bits, and significant bits corresponds to a normal floating-point number with an implied leading `1` bit.

Going through the constraints in section 5.2.4.2.2 of the [draft C standard Keith Thompson linked](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

- This floating-point system plainly conforms to paragraphs 1 and 2 of 5.2.4.2.2 in the draft standard.
- We only represent normalised numbers; paragraph 3 merely permits us to go farther.
- Paragraph 4 is tricky; it says that zero and "values that are not floating-point numbers" may be signed or unsigned.  But paragraph 3 didn't force us to have any values that aren't floating-point numbers, so I can't imagine interpreting paragraph 4 as requiring there to be a zero.
- The range of representable values in paragraph 5 is apparently `-0x1.ffffffffp+16383` to `0x1.ffffffffp+16383`.
- Paragraph 6 states that `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and the math library have implementation-defined accuracy.  Still OK.
- Paragraph 7 doesn't really constrain this implementation as long as we can find appropriate values for all the constants.
- We can set `FLT_ROUNDS` to 0; this way, I don't even have to specify what happens when addition or subtraction overflows.
- `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` shall be 0.
- We don't have subnormals, so `FLT_HAS_SUBNORM` shall be zero.
- `FLT_RADIX` shall be 2, `FLT_MANT_DIG` shall be 32, `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` shall be 10, `FLT_DIG` shall be 9, `FLT_MIN_EXP` shall be -16383, `FLT_MIN_10_EXP` shall be -4933, `FLT_MAX_EXP` shall be 16384, and `FLT_MAX_10_EXP` shall be 4933.
- You can work out `FLT_MAX`, `FLT_EPSILON`, `FLT_MIN`, and `FLT_TRUE_MIN`.

Comment: +1 for a well constructed argument; -1 because I disagree. 8-)} But your hypothetical implementation is not conforming, because cannot meet the requirement to initialize a static floating-point object with no explicit initialization to zero (6.7.9p10). See also my updated answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Heh, nice work.  I *almost* buy it now.  What prohibits me from assigning the closest representable number to 0 to uninitialised floating-point constants of static storage duration?  (And similarly all the other places where a floating-point 0 is assumed?)